# DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []

Tags: apex

Team,

I am creating mock data for a test class and am running into below error.
I have tried everything I could think of and have read many posts on this.

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []
```

The mock data is an opportunity record and one of the values is Unique+External Id field. Also there is a lookup field with filter. 
The unique field is part of an installed package.
The Lookup field is a custom lookup.

```
        Opportunity opp1=new Opportunity(RecordTypeId= opportunityRTId,Name = 'Proposal_Opportunity_1',AccountId = acct.Id,  
                                     UniqueField__c='Test44551',
                                    Amount= 1000,ContractStartDate__c= currentDate.toStartofMonth(),  
                                     ContractEndDate__c= currentDate.addMonths(2).addDays(-1),StageName= 'Open',  
                                     CloseDate = currentDate.addDays(2),LookupField__c = agen.Id,RFP_Due_Date__c=rfpDateTime,OwnerId=owner.Id);                                        
    opptys.add(opp1);                                                                                               
    insert opptys;
```

- I removed field tracking on the object but the error persists
- I tried to split the data insertion but the error persist.

I read the two Salesforce Success posts from 2018 and 2019 about this error type. Nothing worked. One of the post said that a followup 'before insert' trigger might be causing this, so I deactivated the trigger ... but the error persists.

Because the Unique field is part of managed package, I cannot look into the managed package code which might be referring this.

Does anyone know how to debug this error. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting data for a unique field here and if this is a duplicate value, either its already in the system or inserted in the same test class, it would throw the error you mentioned here.
Because this is a test class, the error would not mention the record Id that the unique value is already on.

If you are inserting multiple records at once, you need to pass unique values for all the unique fields for each record.

Comment: I was hitting this error and there were no unique fields which had non-unique values and so I was very perplexed. In the end, I had to move a DML from a unit test to the testsetup to get around this issue (although I've had to do the exact opposite on another occasion).  There are no automations which are populating unique fields with non-unique values either.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. Remove "SeeAllData=TRUE" or use the latest API version, so existing data doesn't impact your mock data
2. If you still face issue, review the mock data insertion logic to ascertain if duplicate records are being inserted. Duplicate records in same insertion batch can also cause these issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while inserting one record only and not having "SeeAllData=TRUE". What helped at the end was removing the @TestSetup from my makeData() method.